# What is the equivalent of a timer job in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Looking at Xamarin documentation, backgrounding appears to have limitations to perform as a timer job.  Backgrounding only runs once, for a max of 7-10 minutes and has to be manually started in code.

How do I make a background tasks that runs every hour in the background and when done, reruns the next hour?  An example of this would be an email client checking for new emails even if the app is closed, or a social network app that display new notifications when the app is inactive.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to check for new content within specific time intervals, iOS7 introduced [background fetch](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_3_ios_backgrounding_techniques/updating_an_application_in_the_background/#Background_Fetch_iOS_7_and_Greater) which allows for running short running tasks at specific time intervals. 
In your case, having a mail client, you could use background fetch to hit your api to see if there is any new content available and in case there is then start a Background task that will download all your new content.

Comment: From my understanding of background fetch, if it takes too long, it kills the app. Does that mean the app has to always be running?  Can you show a local notification for new content alerts?

Comment: @detailCode The OS will give you up to 30 seconds to run code at specific intervals. If the tasks takes more than 30 secs to execute, the OS will kill the process. If your app is not running, it will wake the app and run that specific method. Take a look at this: http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-background-fetch-programming/